# Controller is undefined in StateProvider

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, controller, routes, angular-ui-router

I am using Ionic to make an app and it can't seem to find my controller.  I am unfamiliar with $stateProvider, here is what I have:

routes.js

```
angular.module('app.routes', ['app.controller'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('page', {
    url: '/page1',
    templateUrl: 'templates/page.html',
    controller: 'pageCtrl'
  })

  .state('tabsController.moments', {
url: '/moments',
views: {
  'tab1': {
    templateUrl: 'moments/moments.html',
    controller: 'momentsCtrl'
  }
}
  })
```

moments/moments.Ctrl.js

```
angular.module('app.controller', [])

.controller('momentsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 
function ($scope, $stateParams) {


}])
```

This is the error I am getting:

[image]

I also defined it in my index.html file

Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>



    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->


    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <style type="text/css">
      .platform-ios .manual-ios-statusbar-padding{
        padding-top:20px;
      }
      .manual-remove-top-padding{
        padding-top:0px; 
      }
      .manual-remove-top-padding .scroll{
        padding-top:0px !important;
      }
      ion-list.manual-list-fullwidth div.list, .list.card.manual-card-fullwidth {
        margin-left:-10px;
        margin-right:-10px;
      }
      ion-list.manual-list-fullwidth div.list > .item, .list.card.manual-card-fullwidth > .item {
        border-radius:0px;
        border-left:0px;
        border-right: 0px;
      }
      .show-list-numbers-and-dots ul{
        list-style-type: disc;
        padding-left:40px;
      }
      .show-list-numbers-and-dots ol{
        list-style-type: decimal;
        padding-left:40px;
      }
    </style>

<script src="moments/moments.html"></script>
<script src="camera/camera.html"></script>
<script src="momentList/momentList.html"></script>

     <script src="momentList/momentListCtrl.js"></script>
     <script src="moments/momentsCtrl.js"></script>
     <script src="camera/cameraCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>


    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>




    <!-- Only required for Tab projects w/ pages in multiple tabs 
    <script src="lib/ionicuirouter/ionicUIRouter.js"></script>
    -->

  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
  <div>
  <div>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: post your index file too

Comment: Would you mind posting the text of that error message. It is unreadable

Comment: I'm going to guess one of your other `.js` files has `angular.module('app.controller', [])` in it. This will re-define the module, removing anything previously added

Comment: Thanks @Phil that was the problem.  I had copied some code over and had some duplicate modules.